# <main> CSS not applying in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

So my page is working absolutely fine on FireFox and Google Chrome: http://www.cis130.net/bluehdoj/aboutresponsive

However, the styles I apply to my main tag simply aren't happening in IE11. I tried adding -ms- for the linear gradient but it didn't seem to change anything. If anyone could help me figure this out, I would be very appreciative.

Here's the code:

```
main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 5em;
    max-width: 1000px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6E6E6E 50%, #F90 50%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, #6E6E6E 50%, #F90 50%);
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

and the html:

```
<main>
        <div class="leftCol">
            <h2>Color Scheme Changer</h2>
            <div class="button" id="changeScheme"></div>
            <p>Whatever you do, don't click this button. It's seriously wicked evil. Like the Dirty Bubble, Man-Ray, and Barnacle Boy AKA Every Villian is Lemons evil.</p>
        </div><!--Ends left column-->

        <div class="rightCol">
            <h2>Mirror Mode Button</h2>
            <div class="button" id="mirrorMode"></div>
            <p>This button, however, is pure good. It once saved a bunch of puppies from a burning building. I would highly suggest pressing it.</p>
        </div><!--Ends right column-->
    </main>
```

P.S. this is just a little assignment I've been working on for my into to web dev class and is fine to submit as is but I am a perfectionist plus I would like to know how to avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jan/12/main-HTML5-Tag-not-working-in-Internet-Explorer-91011 try setting `main{display:block}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It s **Not supported** in IE [SOURCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

[image]

try [HTML5 shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv)

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: *facepalm* Excellent haha thank you for that! That was the cure to this mental illness that has plagued me over the past few days.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of a fully browser compatible gradient. You can modify this as an example to create your gradient.

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

I would also like to add that you should not use background-image but rather just background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the gradient then using stops at 50% 50% wont work ! because the color stop 1 stops at 50% and stop 2 starts at 50% right in the middle so you see two boxes of orange and grey, however changing it to 0% and 100% will give you exactly balanced gradient.[Check the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b9W9.jpg)

To visually verify it please check this link from Microsoft itself, where you can generate gradient http://ie.microsoft.com/Testdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html or check the code below:

```
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #6E6E6E 0%, #FF9900 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #6E6E6E 0%, #FF9900 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #6E6E6E 0%, #FF9900 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(, #6E6E6E), color-stop(1, #FF9900));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #6E6E6E 0%, #FF9900 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #6E6E6E 0%, #FF9900 100%);
```